# Null extracted folder for artifact

Tags: androidx

I tried few years ago to learn how to make apps with Android Studio. I now want to try it again and started with a tutorial from 2020. I am a very beginner trying to understand things. So as I read here and there, I found that I might migrate the project (that I got from the tutorial on github) to androidx. So I did it, corrected mistakes/errors but the last one that is giving me a hard time is this one :

Null extracted folder for artifact: ResolvedArtifact(componentIdentifier=androidx.activity:activity:1.8.0, variantName=null....

I read that people had some similar problems and solved it by increasing ram in the gradle.properties or adding lines on the build.gradle like :

```
     implementation ('com.google.android.material:material:1.10.0') {
    exclude group: 'androidx.activity', module: 'activity'
})
```

At the end, nothing worked for me. Does anyone can help knowing that I am a full beginner ?

Thanks :)

Comment: Solved by changing `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.11.0'` to `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'` but if anyone has some explanation:)